# Search for exact string in Indexing services

Tags: indexing-service

I am working on indexing service of `windows server`. I need to search exact word on it. Could you please tell me how I can do it.

Eg: I am searching `Hello World` then how can I get only search for `Hello World`.

I am using following in my indexing search query.

```
WHERE CONTAINS(contents,'Hello World').
```

But its splitting word and searching it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE FREETEXT(Contents,'Hello World')
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also check this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19540/Microsoft-Indexing-Service-How-To)

Comment: Currently I am doing same but its not working. Because of that I am trying with "Content"

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar It's a workaround but can you try it with `proximity` Searching `contains(' "Hello" near() "World" ').`

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar IF you need to search a specific word than you can use `=` operator. http://www3.ha.org.hk/qmh/search/ixqlang.htm